# CEdit::GetLine() windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

I have the following segment of code where `m_edit` is a CEdit control:

```
TCHAR lpsz[MAX_PATH+1];

// get the edit box text
m_edit.GetLine(0,lpsz, MAX_PATH);
```

This works perfectly on computers running Windows XP and earlier.  I have not tested this in Vista, but on Windows 7, lpsz gets junk unicode characters inserted into it (as well as the actual text sometimes).  Any idea as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using MFC, why aren't you taking advantage of its `CString` class? That's one of the reasons many programmers were drawn to MFC, because it makes working with strings so much easier.

For example, you could simply write:

```
int len = m_edit.LineLength(m_edit.LineIndex(0));
CString path;
LPTSTR p = path.GetBuffer(len);
m_edit.GetLine(0, p, len);
path.ReleaseBuffer();
```

(The above code is tested to work fine on Windows 7.)

Note that the copied line does not contain a null-termination character (see the "Remarks" section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7775836w.aspx)). That could explain the nonsense characters you're seeing in later versions of Windows.

Comment: There's a slight risk here.  If another thread might change the edit control's window text between the query for the length and the actual query to get the line.  It's best to use the return value of GetLine to  make sure you have to actual length of the version of the text you just copied.  (Admittedly, this is very rare in most GUI code.)

Comment: @Adrian: Perhaps, but instead of "very rare", I'd say that's simply a "bug". You *want* the app to fail in that case, so you know that you're inadvertently accessing UI controls from a separate thread.

Comment: If your design says controls should only ever be accessed from a particular thread, then, yes, it would be a bug.  Not all GUI code is designed that way.  GetWindowText (which underlies CEdit::GetLine) is specifically designed to deal with grabbing text from another thread or even another process.

Answer (score 4):

It's not null terminated.   You need to do this:

```
int count = m_edit.GetLine(0, lpsz, MAX_PATH);
lpsz[count] = 0;
```