# CEdit::GetLine (MFC, VC++6) returns extra characters in Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, mfc, getline, cedit

m_editText is of type CEdit (from MFC).  This has worked fine for years with hundreds of users in WinXP (32bit), but when the same executable file is on Win7 (64bit) some users are getting (in strText) extra weird (i.e. extended, i.e. garbage) characters appended to the text that they typed in the edit box control (m_editText).  I can't reproduce problem.  I verified that GetLine copied only the characters that are typed into edit box (at least on my machine).

```
TCHAR atchBuffer[256] = {0};  // initialize to all nulls
int nChrCount = m_editText.GetLine(0, atchBuffer, 255);
CString strText;
if (nChrCount!=0)
    strText = CString(atchBuffer);
```

This is compiled (debug build) in Visual C++ 6 on WinXP (32bit), MFC 5 statically linked.  Any insight provided will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637153/ceditgetline-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
if (nChrCount!=0)
    strText = CString(atchBuffer, nChrCount);
```

to make sure that any garbage/uninitialized data does not get added to the CString, only the chars that are in the control.

Comment: Yes, making doubly sure that strText contains only the char's typed into edit box is what we decided to do, since I can't reproduce issue or remote debug it on the few (Win7) machines on which it occurs. Maybe deep inside Windows, something overwrote my 0s in atchBuffer. Thanks.